# CKQuerySubscriptions are not supported in a sharedCloudDatabase

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit, ios10, cksubscription

I noticed that the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/cloudkit/ckquerysubscription) mention that the newly introduced shared CloudKit databases do not support `CKQuerySubscription` (in earlier iOS versions these were called `CKSubscription`). So I guess that means that it is not possible to notify users when privately shared records have changed. Major disappointment. Has anyone run into this problem?

Answer (score 3):

According to the WWDC video about CloudKit this year:

> So, new this year in iOS 10, there's an API called CKDatabaseSubscription.
>
> This allows you to subscribe to any change across an entire database, and it works in a private database, in a shared database.

It shows you how starting on slide 51:

[CloudKit Best Practices WWDC 2016 Presentation Slides](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2016/231bhrh1z1fzrejhbz7/231/231_cloudkit_best_practices.pdf)